# Random hexidecimal color generator in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, random, flashdevelop

I wanted to create the ability to have "random" (pseudo-random) colors generated and came up with this code intended to create all and any color.

I'm very  new to programming and wanted to see if anyone on S.O. had any comments or criticisms, the code works great. Only problem is the colors occasionally being too similar making it difficult to differentiate bewteen them.

I know this is likely a very brute force fashion of coding but its what I thought of.

#### Hexidecimal generator

```
public class colorGenerator 
{
    public var color:int;
    private var randomnumber:Number;
    private var first:String = "";
    
    public function colorGenerator():void
    {
        var colorstring:String = "0x";
        var transfer:String = "0x";
        
        for ( var i:uint = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            randomhex();
            
            colorstring += first;   
        }
        
        transfer = colorstring;
        color = int(transfer);
    }
    
    public function randomhex():void
    {
        randomnumber = Math.random();
    
    
        if ( -1 < randomnumber < ((.99 / 16) * 1))
            first = "0";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*1) < randomnumber < ((.99/16)*2))
            first = "1";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*2)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*3))
            first = "2";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*3)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*4))
            first = "3";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*4)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*5))
            first = "4";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*5)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*6))
            first = "5";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*6)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*7))
            first = "6";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*7)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*8))
            first = "7";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*8)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*9))
            first = "8";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*9)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*10))
            first = "9";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*10)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*11))
            first = "A";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*11)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*12))
            first = "B";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*12)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*13))
            first = "C";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*13)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*14))
            first = "D";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*14)< randomnumber < ((.99/16)*15))
            first = "E";
            
        else if ( ((.99/16)*15)< randomnumber < 2)
            first = "F";
        }
    }
```

I then just assign the hexidecimal value to a variable in another class

```
var acolor:colorGenerator = new colorGenerator;
var COLOR:uint = acolor.color
```

Thanks for any comments!

Comment: Andrew's solutions works good, but if you also want to make sure the colors generated don't look too similar, this page details one method to do so involving the Golden Ratio: http://martin.ankerl.com/2009/12/09/how-to-create-random-colors-programmatically/

Comment: there is Math.random() function just multiply some colorcode as your choice (0xFFFFFF). And you will get all your need. why to write this much of code.

Comment: Trying to increase the "randomness". Considering that Math.random is pseudo-random anyways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work as well.

```
Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF;
```

Comment: I was using this before but didn't have it set to the hexadecimal maximum "FFFFFF". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but this should be more "random":

```
var red : int = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
var green : int = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
var blue : int = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
var color : int = red << 16 | green << 8 | blue;
```

Comment: I tried it out and it definitely works. Much more compact and gave me a better understanding of the hexadecimal color system. Thank you.